Connecting Palantir to Salesforce - how do you access the data tables (the SObjects)?
We’ve followed these Palantir documented connector steps:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/available-connectors/salesforce/
and have established a connection with the Salesforce Connected App, but in the preview do not see any of the Salesforce data tables (SObjects) that contain the data we want to access.
We only see this:

What are we missing?
PS
In the Palantir logs there are multiple of these errors that appear to be blocking the process of finding out about the Salesforce tables:

Error: Invalid HTTP response! System error: UnknownHostException -
xxxxxxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com.

Not clear to me if these originate from Palantir or from Salesforce. I've added an Egress Policy to match at the Palantir side and have added the Palantir IP addresses as Trusted IP Ranges in Network Access in Setup.


Check the accounts permission used for connected app.
you can check the logs on salesforce end as well to get better description.

Seems like you connecting to a dev org, maybe the connected app doesnt have the right permission. If you have a full copy sandbox that could be something you want to look into as well.

Thanks @lancegoh your answer made me double check the Connected App and the "Selected OAUTH Scopes" were wrong. Bit more detail here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/428532/connecting-palantir-to-salesforce-how-do-you-access-the-data-tables-the-sobje.
